# Perform arithmetic on each element of a vector (column) based on the previous vector element over multiple vectors (columns) in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 12 columns, and I need to perform some basic arithmetic on 7 of them: columns 5:12. The data frame, named test is pasted below.

The arithmetic I am looking to perform would change each element based on the previous element except for the first in each column as the arithmetic for the first element of each column is different than the subsequent elements. Also, the element vector would be changed by the equation as its original value is involved. I did the arithmetic for the first element in a previous line of code, so that's already the correct value.

Here is the math:

```
B = (1-.08)Bt + .08(z)
```

where Bt is the previous element's value and z is the current element's value. Each element will then become B.

EDIT: I probably wasn't clear, but Bt will be the newly calculated value of B from the previous element. So this has a step by step progression.

I've been attempting this with apply, but I'm confused because I've only done something similar on single vectors in the past with a for loop, but in that case, I created brand new vector elements based on previous elements, and like this example, the first element was pre-defined.

I can conceptualize this, but can't code it with my current skill set in R.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Data:

[image: test table]

```
 test <- 

 structure(list(Forecast_day = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), Forecast_date = structure(c(17555, 
    17556, 17557, 17558, 17559, 17560), class = "Date"), DeliveryDate = structure(c(17563, 
    17564, 17565, 17566, 17567, 17568), class = "Date"), HourEnding = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Coast = c(-0.0459999999999999, -11.6, -3.8, 
    -7.09999999999999, -9.6, -11.2), East = c(0.01, -8.5, -1.5, -3.5, 
    -0.5, -9.5), FarWest = c(-0.07, -6.5, -9, -11.5, 6, -10.5), North = c(0.01, 
    -2.5, -1.5, -1.5, 14, 0), NorthCentral = c(-0.07, -7.25, -5.75, 
    -10.75, 6.75, 1.5), SouthCentral = c(-0.01, -10, -8.5, -3.5, 
    -8.5, -11), Southern = c(-0.04, -10.8, -4.6, -7.8, -9.6, -12), 
        West = c(-0.16, -7.4, -6.6, -13.2, 7.8, -9)), .Names = c("Forecast_day", 
    "Forecast_date", "DeliveryDate", "HourEnding", "Coast", "East", 
    "FarWest", "North", "NorthCentral", "SouthCentral", "Southern", 
    "West"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does something like this work? `dplyr::mutate_at(test, 5:12, funs((1-.08) * dplyr::lag(.) + .08 * .))`

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately. I get NA in the first row across columns 5:12 and the subsequent values aren't correct.

Comment: Is there a way to start this code at the second element of each column? That should work.

Comment: Since the first row is already correct, you can always just re-replace that row. Ex. do `r1 <- test[1, ]` then run the above `mutate_at` call, then do `test[1, ] <- r1`.

Comment: Or in one step as `test %>% mutate_at(5:12, funs((1 - .08)*lag(., default = .[1]) + 0.08*. ))`

Comment: Renu, that works, but only for the 2nd row across the columns. The subsequent values 3:6 are slight variations of the original values. I'm not sure why it doesn't work...

Comment: C. Braun, the problem there from what I see is that the first column is pulling in an NA and forcing incorrect calculations for the remainder of the elements in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Reduce` meta-function to sequentially apply the arithmetic along a vector, using the previous result as one of the inputs.

First, wrap the arithmetic in a function.

```
update_with_previous <- function(previous, current) {
  (1 - 0.08) * previous + 0.08 * current
}
```

To do it for one column, use the function in `Reduce` and set `accumulate = TRUE` to keep each result.

```
Reduce(update_with_previous, test$Coast, accumulate = TRUE)
# [1] -0.046000 -0.970320 -1.196694 -1.668959 -2.303442 -3.015167
```

Use `lapply` to replace multiple columns at the same time.

```
test[5:12] <- lapply(
  X          = test[5:12],
  FUN        = Reduce,
  f          = update_with_previous,
  accumulate = TRUE
)
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I was not aware of Reduce. Look like I'll be migrating away from Excel completely sooner than later. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something more elegant out there, but I think this would work:

```
B <- function(Bt,z) (1-.08)*Bt + .08*(z)
tmp <- sapply(test[,5:12] ,function(g) sapply(2:nrow(test),function(x) B(Bt = g[x-1],z = g[x])))
test[2:nrow(test),5:12] <-  tmp
```

Comment: This definitely works, but is still not calculating correct values. I apologize if I wasn't clear, but I was hoping to use the newly calculated value of B for each element in the following element's calculation as Bt. Although, your g[x-1] should cover that.... Not sure why it's not working.